# Jquery: .One() method implementation issue

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make the following part of a Jquery script to only be run once

```
$(this).siblings('.youtubevideo').find("iframe").prop.one("src", function(){
    return $(this).data("src");
});
```

***I need for only that part to be run once, as the rest of the script needs to run whenever the element is clicked.***

The complete script is this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".youtubebbcode_button").off('click').click(function() {
      $(this).siblings('.youtubevideo').slideToggle("medium");
      $(this).siblings('.youtubevideo').css("display","inline-block");
      $(this.parentNode).toggleClass("youtubebbcode_open");
      $(this).siblings('.youtubevideo').find("iframe").prop("src", function(){
        return $(this).data("src");
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Also, this script is inside a BBCode in a forum, so the element with the script will be repeated multiple times in a given topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.one()` only to fire *events* once and not property assignment.

Add a check for property considering initially the `src` is empty.

```
var $iframe = $(this).siblings('.youtubevideo').find("iframe");
if(!$iframe.prop('src').length){
    $iframe.prop("src", function(){
        return $(this).data("src");
    });
}
```

or just,

```
...
$iframe.prop("src", function(){
    var src = $(this).prop("src");
    return src.length? src : $(this).data("src");
});
...
```

Note : The 2nd option would render the iframe again. Prefer 1st one.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `src` attribute, if it is empty or undifined then execute your code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".youtubebbcode_button").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.youtubevideo').slideToggle("medium");
        $(this).siblings('.youtubevideo').css("display","inline-block");
        $(this.parentNode).toggleClass("youtubebbcode_open");

        var iframe = $(this).siblings('.youtubevideo').find("iframe")
        if(!iframe.attr("src").trim()) { 
             iframe.attr("src", function() {
                return $(this).data("src");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've been clearer. This script is inside a BBCode in a forum and will be set multiple times in the document, so the script is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in condition like:

```
  if(!$(this).siblings('.youtubevideo').find("iframe").prop("src")){
         $(this).siblings('.youtubevideo').find("iframe").prop("src", function(){
                return $(this).data("src");
          });
  }
```

It will ensure if SRC attribute is undefined or blank then only get in to execute.